# Default Intent for launcher Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

### What is value of Intent of launcher activity

hello friends, I'm new to android. I'm working on android `activity` and `Intent`. As i did in my launcher activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

and in second activity i use `getIntent()` method to get an reference of calling intent in `OnCreate` method as:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
if(in != null) //do something..
```

In second activity `getIntent()` method return the reference of calling `intent`. But when I Use `getIntent()` method in `onCreate` method of launcher activity, its value was **not** null. So what reference is passed to intent when we use `getIntent()` method in launcher activity

Answer (score 0):

Well the Android OS starts the activity when you click your app_icon, it looks through your manifest file and finds the launcher activity and then launches it

Comment: I want to know that what reference or value intent will hold if i use getIntent() method.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to know that

Answer (score 0):

Get the intent which has started your activity using the getIntent() method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Your data is represented as strings, then you can use intent.getStringExtra(String name) method. In your case:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```